# V-I Tester (aka ASA or Octopus or curve tracer)

Tags: instrumentation, iv-curve

I want to build a simple V-I tester and based on [this article](https://www.jammarcade.net/simple-component-tester-a-k-a-octopus-curve-tracer/) (or [this](https://www.qsl.net/kd7rem/pdf/octopus.pdf)) I did this easy circuit:

[image]

**R1 = 560Ω

R2 = 100Ω

R3 = 1kΩ**

where **R1** and **R2** is a voltage divider to set the \$V_{(DUT+V_{R_3})}=1VAC\$ and R3 limit the current in the **D**evice **U**nder **T**est.

I used [this](https://it.rs-online.com/web/p/trasformatori-per-montaggio-a-pannello/0504561) transformer, with 6.3V, 10 VA output (is dual, but I use only one output).

My question:

1. If I change the voltage divider resistors to \$R_1=56Ω\$ and \$R_2= 10Ω\$ (especially), isn't better? With **10Ω** I will reduce the output impedance of the circuit that feed the DUT,  thus I don't load the source because it is in parallel to the \$R_3+R_{DUT}\ge1000Ω\$ and then \$R_3+R_{DUT}\gg R_1\$, isn't?
   BTW the current I draw is \$I =\frac{6.3}{66} \approx 100mA\$ and the output power is at the "safe" value of:  \$6.3V\cdot100mA = 0.63VA\$
2. With this voltage divider I have a voltage less than 1VAC across the DUT. The article says that I can test also Diode, Zener, etc. How is possible with this small voltage?

Comment: Just to say that R3 "limit" the current through device, but is also the "measure" sensor of this current. Point 2: diodes need only 0.7V ... current is always "exp", and the scale doesn't matter. You can't determine the Zener point if the voltage is too low.

Comment: Point 1: changing values is not really useful, because R3 limits the current. NB: adding a battery, one pot, and one resistor to control current, should also be used for testing and tracing curves of quasi any type of "transistor" ...

Comment: @antonio51, Where you will put a battery?

Comment: Transistors have 3 pins. - Collector (wired to X, a diode should be useful, voltage positive for NPN, negative for PNP ), - Emitter (wired to ground): C-E are used as DUT (gives Vce vs ~IC). Between Base and Emitter - a well-chosen resistor and a battery in the right position to set base current.

Comment: @Antonio, What is the need for the voltage divider R1-R2? Why should you limit the voltage to 1 V?

Comment: @Circuitfantasist - Divider R1- "R2 variable" only to limit the excursion of max voltage on DUT (some kind of current protection). For low current, it is enough and easy through R2. For high currents, a variable transformer (or a "fast" triangular voltage pulse with a low duty cycle) should be needed to adjust the voltage applied on DUT (as on a professional Curves-tracer), but with a scheme of "power" protection (so the calculation of v*i on the DUT is necessary to remain under Pmax) ...

Comment: @Antonio51, I understand your considerations. In the early 90's, I created a computerized curve tracer for my students where the software monitored Pmax = V*I. The most [sophisticated experiment](https://photos.app.goo.gl/2vT87FTkeYMcHvQT6) was measuring and plotting a 3-dimensional BJT output characteristic on the screen. But now I use this extremely simple curve tracer in the laboratory (my students mount it on a small prototyping board).

Comment: @Circuitfantasist  It is a very good exercise in a lab and helps to understand some drawing functions (mathematical with scope) and electronic characteristics of DUT. This simple circuit is very useful. I used this simple curve tracer about 55 years ago with my "own scope made" ... and a professional tool Philips (https://www.radiomuseum.org/r/philips_transistor_curve_tracer_pm_6507.html) 5 years later at university.

Comment: @Antonio51, since I can see that your avatar is a tunnel diode IV curve, maybe [this experiment](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xx35oA9aC4mfNdQAJsz3CryAqDAAynBC/view?usp=drivesdk) will be interesting for you:-)

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Very good. Thank you. NB: if you change the resistor to the "right" "load" (high enough), you should see the "full" curve ...  :-)

Comment: @Antonio51, You probably mean "low resistance enough"? Exactly! I should buffer the 1 k voltage divider by an op-amp follower... and maybe, remove the resistance by a transimpedance amplifier...  but then I was in a hurry and I didn't do it... I have considered these modes in [my Wikibooks story](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Negative_Differential_Resistance) about negative differential resistance.

Comment: No. "High" resistance to "exceed" the negative resistance and make the whole circuit "stable" ...

Comment: ... but I made it in this [computerized arrangement](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XQxhwr-mtebAJ-GisCNAZLdOWWjbRy6Y/view?usp=drivesdk)...

Comment: I mean we need low resistance in the case of an N-shaped NDR (tunnel diode) and high resistance in the case of an S-shaped NDR (neon lamp) to see the negative resistance region...

Comment: Right. I forget that the axes for the "tunnel" curve are reversed! I used only the load line for the curves of UJT (V vs i) ...  :-(

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do, with a little effort ...
This is for BJT-type **NPN**. Here, R4 is stepped 100 k -> 1000 k.
See the "visual" change of "beta" ...

[image]

@Circuit fantasist ... and all those interested :-) ...
Here is a simulation to explain the choice of "voltage" and "resistor" to see the full curve of a DUT with "negative" resistance (NB: Voltage vs current, as with UJT device) ...
NB: the part of the "unstable zone" can't be seen if the 2 conditions (voltage, resistance) of "loading" are not met.

[image]